# Is my follower trying to tell me something when they say, "I don't like the looks of this."

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim, I've had multiple occasions where my followers have remarked, "I don't like the looks of this." and every time, I've ended up going into a battle where I've died multiple times.  It's almost as if the follower knew I didn't have the experience needed to win the fight.

Is it just 'something they say'? Or is there more to it? Are they telling me that to warn me?

Comment: Possibly, but I've had a companion tell me this multiple times, and I've never had much trouble. Possibly remarking on if they are "bosses"?

Comment: I'm almost certain there's no relative success calculation, as I've heard this before bosses I was clearly capable of dealing with. I think they just say it when you pass by certain areas.

Answer (score 5):

You'll find that companions have a list of sayings like:
"*I don't like the look of this*"
"*Watch your head on low bits of rock*"
"*This place smells funny*"
"*Don't go to far, you might not come out*" - that's what she said!

They say them whenever they enter a dungeon. It means there might be enemies nearby but that's nothing to worry about. They're just big sissies.

On a side note, if you take them somewhere with a nice view they'll say something like "*Wow, would you look at that?*"

Comment: Or Lydia's personal favorite, "Look! A cave! I wonder what's inside," _after_ we've explored the cave. Companion fail.

Comment: Who is this Lydia everyone keeps talking about? She sounds lame. I got me a cool mage and now I'm INVINSIBLE!!! His favourite line is "I'm an apprentice battle mage, not pack mule... oh ok"

Comment: @Coomie Lydia is the housecarl and follower you get from becoming a Thane in Whiterun (the first major city). Her passive-aggressive personality quickly makes [her misfortunes](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MTMwjYgJsFQ) amusing.

Comment: @Bryan It seems like everyone has Lydia as a companion. I must have missed her somehow... Funny video

Comment: @Coomie She is a "housecarl" you get after you become Thane of Whiterun. If you've completed those quests (you probably have, they come very early in the game), you can pick her up in Dragonreach.

Comment: @Coomie You probably got Marcurio, from Riften (also my follower of choice). Lydia can be had as follower once you [continue in the main quest and killed the dragon in that quest](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dragon_Rising) and become the Thane of Whiterun (if you haven't done this quest, I believe dragons won't randomly spawn throughout Skyrim). List of all possible followers in Skyrim here: http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Followers

Comment: @galacticninja Marcurio is my companion right now. But I had a better one, Areana Lenith. She was great, never ran into me, not like Marcurio... But unfortunately I gave her to the Blades... :(